# How to Filter Order History on Customer Account?

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, orders, customer-account

I have added a Column on Order Table `is_hidden`, If an Order is set `is_hidden = 1` then I want to hide that order from Customer Order List in Customer Account on Frontend.

How can I add aditional filter on the Order Collection without updating Core File.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can field your order Collection using another way [Magento Plugin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html).

Create  after Method  {`afterGetOrders`} on `getOrders()` at plugin class and filter by  `is_hidden = 1`.

**Create di.xml and code Like:**

```
<config>
    <type name="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History">
      <plugin name="{pluginName}" type="{VendorName}\{Modulename}\Plugin\HistoryPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Plugin Class:**

```
namespace {VendorName}\{Modulename}\Plugin;

class HistoryPlugin
{
   public function afterGetOrders(\Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History $subject, $result)
    {
    if($result &&  $result->getSize() > = 1){
      return $result->addFieldToFilter('is_hidden',['null'=> true]);    
    }
       return $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Appliying  `$result->addFieldToFilter('is_hidden',['neq'=> 1]);`  hides all the orders, including the one with `is_hidden = NULL`

Comment: is_hidden is field boolean field ?

Comment: And When I do `$result->addFieldToFilter('is_hidden',['eq'=> 1]);`  **Equals to**, It does gives the list of `is_hidden = 1` items

Comment: yes is_hidden is a boolean field, and it include value NULL 0(where NULL and 0 are not hidden), and 1

Comment: `addFieldToFilter('is_hidden',array('null' => true))`, try this

Comment: it is working great for `is_hidden = NULL` but  fails When the value is `is_hidden = 0`

Comment: it is working for `is_hidden = NULL` but no working When the value is is_hidden = 0, if you find it plz let me know, thanks

Comment: Pagination is not updated from the above solution...?

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History` in your custom module by using preference.

in your custom extension's `etc/di.xml` add preference

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History" type="YouPackage\YourModule\Block\Order\History" />
```

**Note: You can also use plugin afterGetOrders() if you find that more suitable.**

Now in overridden class, you can add filter to below method

> Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History::getOrders();

Use addFieldToFilter('is_hidden', 0); to get orders only with is_hidden set to 0.

Or you can also try not in array like below

```
$this->orders = $this->getOrderCollectionFactory()->create($customerId)->addFieldToSelect(
                '*'
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'status',
                ['in' => $this->_orderConfig->getVisibleOnFrontStatuses()]
            )->addFieldToFilter(
                'is_hidden',
                ['nin' => [1]]
            )->setOrder(
                'created_at',
                'desc'
            );
```